# How do I fill my validAccounts array-it shows that there are null values in it

Tags: java

*How can i make sure my validAccounts array does not have null values?**

This program is an ATM program that uses a text file and checks to see if the user's password and account number matches the possible passwords and balance from the text file

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

 public class ATM2 {
 public static Scanner kbd;
 public static final int MAXSIZE = 60000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = null;
    String[] validAccounts = new String[MAXSIZE];
    int lineNum = 1;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(new File("ATMdata.txt"));
        // counts how many lines are in text
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line;
            line = input.nextLine();
            lineNum++;

        }
        // sets the array to the number of lines in text
        validAccounts = new String[lineNum];
        // prints out the number of lines in text
        System.out.println(lineNum);

        input.close();

    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error opening one of the files.");
    }

    try {

        int count = 0;
        input = new Scanner(new File("ATMdata.txt"));
        // counts how many lines are in text
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line;
            line = input.nextLine();

            validAccounts[count] = line;
            count++;
         System.out.println(line);
        }
        input.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error opening file");
    }

    System.out.println("What is your account number?");
    String acctNum = kbd.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the password?");
    String pwd = kbd.nextLine(); 
    checkID(acctNum,  pwd,validAccounts); 



}

// Each entry in the validAccounts array is assumed to be holding:
// the account number followed by
// a space, followed by
// the password for the account
// followed by a space
// followed by the current balance.

public static String checkID(String acctNum, String pwd,
        String[] validAccounts) {
    String account = "" ;
    String password = "" ;
    String balance; 
String result = "error"; 
//This is supposed to check the array for a valid input
for(int i = 0; i <validAccounts.length ; i ++){
    **//It is giving me an error for the line below-if anyone could help me figure it           out!**
    int space1 = validAccounts[i].indexOf(" ");//ERROR
    account = validAccounts[i].substring(0, space1);
    int space2 = validAccounts[i].indexOf(" ", space1 + 1);
    password = validAccounts[i].substring(validAccounts[i].indexOf(" ") + 1, space2);
    balance = validAccounts[i].substring(validAccounts[i].lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);

}
if (acctNum.equals(account)){
    return account;
}
if(pwd.equals(password)){
    return password; 

}       return result;
}
```

}

Comment: When you debug this, which object is `null`?  Where do you think that object is getting a value?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? set a breakpoint and run it.

Comment: int space1 = validAccounts[i].indexOf(" ")//giving me a null point exception. It is showing an error there.

Comment: add the stacktrace of error.

Comment: checkID(acctNum,  pwd,validAccounts);//it is showing an error there as well but thats probbaly because there is an null point exception in the checkID method

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Set a breakpoint on the `input = new Scanner(new File("ATMdata.txt"));` and evaluate `input.hasNextLine()` - it'll be false! Possibly a path problem?

The obvious failure mode would be that no elements are being added to your `validAccounts` array.

IIRC `Scanner.nextLine()` doesn't return `null` so the problem has to be that the `while (input.hasNextLine()) {` block is never entered, and since you have

```
String[] validAccounts = new String[MAXSIZE];
```

(which will be 60k `null`'s) you got an NPE. You should read up on `java.util.List`

Cheers,

Comment: It reassigns the array, so it will be full of `null`s.

Comment: Yes there is a given text file with possible passwords and account numbers at the text file

Comment: @GáborBakos but values are put into the reassigned array after reassignment... Look for the `validAccounts[count] = line;` line

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String checkID(String acctNum, String pwd,
    String[] validAccounts) {
    String account = "" ;
    String password = "" ;
    String balance; 
    String result = "error"; 
    //This is supposed to check the array for a valid input
    for(int i = 0; i <validAccounts.length ; i ++){
        if(validAccounts[i]!=null){    
            int space1 = validAccounts[i].indexOf(" ");//ERROR
            account = validAccounts[i].substring(0, space1);
            int space2 = validAccounts[i].indexOf(" ", space1 + 1);
            password = validAccounts[i].substring(validAccounts[i].indexOf(" ") + 1, space2);
            balance = validAccounts[i].substring(validAccounts[i].lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
        }
    }
    if (acctNum.equals(account)){
        return account;
    }
    if(pwd.equals(password)){
        return password; 
    }       
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and now it is not printing anything at all

Comment: yes, this code protected your program from crashing, but it proves that validAccounts[i] is null inside the loop. So the problem now is why there's a null value in this array

Comment: I added a print statement that checks to see if the array has the contents of the text file and it seems to be printing out correctly